# Why I'm getting clang warning: no previous prototype for function 'diff'

Tags: c++, function, pointers, warnings, clang

I have the following declaration in my code:

```
//Central diff function, makes two function calls, O(h^2)
REAL diff(const REAL h, const REAL x, REAL (*func)(const REAL))
{
    // diff = f(x + h) - f(x -h)/2h + O(h^2)
    return ((*func)(x + h) - (*func)(x - h))/(2.0*h + REALSMALL);
}
```

This goes in a "utils.h" file. When I compile a test using it it gives me:

```
clang++ -Weverything tests/utils.cpp -o tests/utils.o   
In file included from tests/utils.cpp:4:
tests/../utils/utils.h:31:6: warning: no previous prototype for function 'diff' [-Wmissing-prototypes]
REAL diff(const REAL h, const REAL x, REAL (*func)(const REAL))
```

What I`m missing here ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you *defined* (not *declared*) your function in a header then you should make it inline. Change:

```
REAL diff(const REAL h, const REAL x, REAL (*func)(const REAL))
```

to:

```
inline REAL diff(const REAL h, const REAL x, REAL (*func)(const REAL))
```

Or just move the definition into a .c file and keep just a prototype in the header file.